# Authenticated users with STS and API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

If my user send a request to STS requesting for credentials:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.WebIdentityCredentials({
  RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::{id}:role/{role}',
  WebIdentityToken: idToken,
  RoleSessionName: VALUE
});
```

Later, when the user sends a request to a private API Gateway endpoint, by using RoleSessionName I could know who is the person making the request. But how can we avoid another user to assume his identity by using the same RoleSessionName?

What is the best way to authenticate users using STS and IAM roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RoleSessionName is just an identifier for the assumed session. It shouldn't be used as a mechanism to differentiate the callers.

The assumed role is the "effective" principal in this case. If you want the API to behave differently based on the user, then please use unique role for each user.

Answer (score 0):

`RoleSessionName` is the way to tell each user apart. One cannot create a separate role for each user because each account can only have 1000 roles at most. I think this API call is not meant to be used on client side for authentication purpose. It's only meant to give a role to an already authenticated user on server side.